# How does my browser know to include a cookie in initial request?

Tags: http, cookies, web-scraping, request-headers

I am trying to build a web scraper for the following site:

https://webdiplomacy.net/gamelistings.php

When I visit there on my browser, my initial request includes a Cookie in the headers.

```
Cookie: __utma=56936876.27553852.1525640664.1525640664.1525640664.1; __utmc=56936876; __utmz=56936876.1525640664.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmb=56936876.4.10.1525640664
```

How does my browser generate this cookie, and how does it know to include a cookie - given that I am visiting this page in an incognito window without having visited another page?

There is no set-cookie header in the response.

gamelistings.php is the first file accessed in the request. How does my browser know to include specific data when it is first accessing the site?

Surely the procedure for generating a cookie must be contained in the website, but this cannot be the case since my browser is generating a cookie before it ever actually receives any data (since this is the first request).

How could I possibly generate such a cookie with a web scraper?

Answer (score 0):

They are [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage) cookie. Are you sure you have not visited another site, not even google search? I can't reproduce your problem on ubuntu, firefox.